# Saving changes to a multivalued ComboBox via AuditTrail

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010, audit-trail

I have a Access 2010 Database using a multivalued field (the Access inbuilt way to have m:n-relation between two tables).
To keep track of changes to the database I use an AuditTrail VBA procedure every time the corresponding form is updated, saving all the changes to history table.

Now, when I change the value of the ComboBox and the loop reaches the ComboBox bound to the multivalued field, the procedure throws an error because of incompatible Data types:

```
    For Each ctl In Screen.ActiveForm.Controls
    If ctl.Tag = "History" Then
        If Nz(ctl.Value) <> Nz(ctl.OldValue) Then
            With rst
                .AddNew
                ![timestamp] = datTimeCheck
                ![UserName] = strUserID
                ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
                ![recordid] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
                ![FieldName] = ctl.ControlSource
                ![beforeValue] = ctl.OldValue
                ![afterValue] = ctl.Value
                .Update
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next ctl
```

How do I get the actual `Value` and the `OldValue` from a combobox converted to string in VBA?

I tried `combobox.focus` and then `combobox.Text`
This works, but doesnt help with the `OldValue` problem.

How to properly use the `value` and `oldvalue` property of comboboxes? The official VBA object reference for comboboxes doesn't help at all.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821691.aspx

Comment: thank you @Andre for your change. I am not a native and my Access is in German so i have to translate everything ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an elegant solution, only a quick & dirty workaround:

Modify your code so that it checks differently ComboBox1 and the other controls.
The `.Value` and `.OldValue` are basically an array of variants.

```
Dim afterValue as variant
Dim beforeValue as Variant

For Each ctl In Screen.ActiveForm.Controls
    If ctl.Tag = "History" Then
        If Ctl.name = "ComboBox1" then
           err.clear
           on error resume next
           I=0
           afterValue = ""
           beforeValue = ""
           while err=0
               '
               ' Throws an error if 'out of range', i.e. after the last value
               '
               afterValue = afterValue + Nz(Cstr(ComboBox1.Value(I))) + ";"
               beforeValue = beforeValue + Nz(Cstr(ComboBox1.OldValue(I))) + ";"

           wend
        else
           afterValue = ctl.Value
           beforeValue = Nz(ctl.OldValue)
        endif
        If Nz(ctl.Value) <> a$ Then
           With rst
              .AddNew
              ![timestamp] = datTimeCheck
              ![UserName] = strUserID
              ![FormName] = Screen.ActiveForm.Name
              ![recordid] = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(IDField).Value
              ![FieldName] = ctl.ControlSource
              ![beforeValue] = beforeValue
              ![afterValue] = afterValue
              .Update
           End With
        End If
    End If
Next ctl
```

Comment: ComboBox already has a builtin .OldValue property which, i assume, is working alright.
My problem is that i dont understand how to get the "text" value from the .Value or .OldValue property.

Answer (score 2):

When `ctl` references a multi-valued combo box with at least one item selected, your test condition ...

```vb
Nz(ctl.Value) <> Nz(ctl.OldValue)
```

... will certainly throw a type mismatch error.  In that situation, `ctl.Value` is actually a variant array, and `Nz()` can't cope with it.  The problem is essentially the same as this ...

```vb
Debug.Print Nz(Array(1,2,3)) '<- type mismatch error
```

Perhaps you would prefer to grab a string of the concatenated combo selections ...

```vb
Debug.Print Join(ctl.Value, ",")
```

If that seems useful, beware that `ctl.Value` will be Null when none of its items is selected.  And attempting to `Join()` Null will also trigger type mismatch error.

Note those issues also apply to `ctl.OldValue`.

But there may be yet another complication.  Based on my testing I'm skeptical whether `OldValue` is reliable for a multi-valued combo box.  If you also find that to be the case, use the form's current event to store the combo's initial selections in a form level variable and reference that variable (instead of `OldValue`) in your audit procedure.